# HTTPS with nginx, fastAPI, docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, fastapi

I'm using nginx for my FARM stack app. I'm running into an issue with my APIs not going through HTTPS it works on HTTP. I've tried removing the server 80 block still getting the same issue.

Here's the error

```
docker-fastapi    | [2021-04-10 01:02:36 +0000] [9] [WARNING] Invalid HTTP request received. proxy-app         | 2021/04/10 01:02:36 [error] 22#22: *15 peer closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 192.168.249.11, server: xxxx, request: "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://192.168.160.2:8080/api/", host: "xxx"
```

Heres the nginx conf file

```
upstream docker_fastapi {
    server docker-fastapi:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location ~ /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://docker_fastapi;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name xxxx;
    client_max_body_size 12m;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx.key;
    server_tokens off;
    add_header X-Frame-Options sameorigin always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header Set-Cookie "lcid=1043; Max-Age=60";

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ /api/ {
        proxy_pass https://docker_fastapi;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

I pretty much copied this repo to try to get HTTPS to work
https://github.com/geekyjaat/fastapi-react

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, your proxy passes the request to your API at https://192.168.160.2:8080/api/. However, the HTTPS certificate relies on the domain name. When you use an IP address, there will be an error about SSL connection between Nginx and upstream as you can see in the log :

```
closed connection in SSL handshake while SSL handshaking to upstream
```

You can run your API in HTTP.  To pass the request to your API from the nginx proxy, change your configuration in the server 443 block from :

```
  proxy_pass https://docker_fastapi;
```

to :

```
  proxy_pass http://docker_fastapi;
```

Comment: I've tried that but then I get an error from the browser about mixed content since the API call is through HTTP

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xxxx' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://xxx/api/reports/xxx'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Edit: One more thing. The site is an internal site with a self signed cert. Would that be the issue there?

Comment: You can call API using HTTPS. I mean, you send the request to the address of NGINX server 443 block, then the request will be pass to your API. It is how a reverse proxy works

Comment: I figured it out after all wasn't nginx issue. Was my API calls had a trailing slash and it was rerouting to HTTPS. Without the trailing forward slash it called correctly. Thanks!